# How to associate multiple fxml files with single controller

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I have multiple FXML files with different content and I want to associate these FXML files with single controller. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but not recommend. Why not to use multiple controllers?

Comment: Do *not* attempt this. At best, it will be very hard to keep track of which fields are initialized at what stage. If you have an `initialize()` method, it will be called once for each FXML file... any time you have a method called `initialize()` that is called multiple times, you know you are not using things the way they were intended to be used.

Comment: You should think :  1 FXML = 1 Controller or 1 Component = 1 FXML = 1 Controller

Comment: I could only see this if you had the same screen displayed two radically different ways and it was easier to get those looks using two fxml files, is that what you are doing?

Comment: @dwaddell Even then, you might use the same controller *class*, but surely not the same controller instance. By "single controller", I think the OP is referring to the same instance.

Comment: @James_D Very true, I was merely taking a guess on a scenario where I could see someone thinking it would make sense.